# How to combine 2 Vectors in a JList?

Tags: java, vector, jlist

```
Vector<String> totalProducts = Products.getProductNames();
Vector<String> selectedProducts = Products.getSelectedProductNames();
```

The *selectedProducts* vector is a subvector of *totalProducts* (meaning that *selectedProducts* contains one, more or all of the elements from *totalProducts*). What I want is to combine these two vectors and make a single *JList*, which contains all the elements from totalProducts, and with the elements of selectedProducts already *selected*.

What I tried:

```
    Vector<Integer> indices = new Vector<Integer>();
    JList prdList = new JList(totalProducts);
    for(int i = 0; i < totalProducts.size(); i++)
    {
        for(String name : selectedProducts)
        {
            if(totalProducts.contains(name)) indices.add(i);
        }
    }
    Object [] objIndices = indices.toArray();
    //... Cast from Object [] to int [] ....
    prdList.setSelectedIndices(intIndices);
```

...but this selects all the elements in the final JList.

Previously I tried:

```
    JList prdList = new JList(totalProducts);
    for(String tName : totalProducts)
    {
        for(String sName : selectedProducts)
        {
            if(totalProducts.contains(sName)) prdList.setSelectedValue(sName, false);
        }
    }
```

...but this one selected only the last element from the selectedProducts.

Can you please help me to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt that selects all items does so because you're iterating over each item, and if *any* item from the selectedProducts list is in the total list, adds the iteration item's index to the final selection list. Try changing your loop to something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < totalProducts.size(); i++)
{
    String name = totalProducts.get(i);
    if(selectedProducts.contains(name)) indices.add(i);
}
```

Comment: It works now. I knew why my first attempt selected all items, I just wrote it for a starting point. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

in debugging your first attempt (which looks like it *should* work, what was the contents of your intIndices array?  because that looks like it should work, presuming your array conversion works.

however, since `selectedproducts` is guaranteed to be less items than total, you might want to iterate over that instead?

```
List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>(selectedProducts.size());    
for(String name : selectedProducts)
{
    int index = totalProducts.indexOf(name);
    if (index != -1)
        indices.add(index);        
}
```

although, since `indexOf` is a linear search through a list, it probably doesn't make much of a difference either way.

as for your second attempt, the ListSelectionModel has methods for *adding* a selected index (`addSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1)`)
, you're using the one that *sets* (overwrites) the selection.

see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html

aside: you might want to use `List<>` instead of `Vector<>`, as vector has a lot of unecessary synchronization overhead.  Unless you *need* the synchronization....

**edit** fixed copy+paste of add(i) with add(index)

Comment: The intIndices is the objArray casted to int. The conversion is correct. The code you provided here doesn't work. It always selects the first n elements of the JList, where n is the number of elements of the selectedProducts. If I have 3 elements in the selectedProducts, the first 3 elements of the totalProducts will be selected in the Jlist.

Comment: As for List<>, you meant ArrayList<>? Because as far as I know, List cannot have arguments (like <String>). And I use Vectors over ArrayLists, because I can't make a JList from an ArrayList, only from a Vector.

Comment: the default constructors may not allow List (for backwards compatibility reasons before the generic collecitons were added), but you can easily make your own implementation of ListModel.  List certainly allows generic arguments, as it is just an interface: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: Now your code works too. Thanks! You are right about JList constructors, and also about List allowing generic arguments, as it results from the docs. But without any modifications and simply using `List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>(selectedProducts.size());` gives me an error in eclipse: _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer>_

Comment: are you importing java.awt.* too?  If so, then the awt version of List might be what its complaining about? try adding `import java.util.List`; as your last import?

Comment: I was importing only `java.awt.List`; adding `import java.util.List;` solved the problem. Thanks!